# Magento 2 - Why has difference between machine when run di:compile?

Tags: magento2, compiler, di

In magento2, Why has  difference between machine when run setup:di:compile ?

In machine A:

[image]

In machine B:

[image]

How to config: when we compile it does not do "interception cache generation..." ? (I would like it run is the same machine B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they both do the same.

The terminal in B simply does not seem to support carriage return (to overwrite / update the same line) and colors.

In both screenshots step 7/7 is interception cache generation.

Comment: If do is the same machine B, it will lose time more than machine A?